# vba set combobox value to multiple cells in multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have 3 combo-boxes and an OK button. I need to set the value of multiple cells in multiple worksheets equal to the value of the combo box selection.

```
Dim choice As String
Dim x As Variant

x = Array("STD BASE DD", "STD BASE CAB DOOR ONLY", "OPEN BASE CABINET", _
    "1 DRAWER BASE & OPEN", "2 DRAWER BASE", "3 DRAWER BASE", "4 DRAWER BASE", _
    "5 DRAWER BASE")
    
    choice = matsetup.ComboBox1.Value

   Worksheets(x).Range("H14,H15,H20").Value = choice
```

This gives an error "object doesn't support property or method".

```
Worksheets(x).Range("H14,H15,H20").Value = choice
```

Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO. I don't see a question. Are you having problems setting the values or is the code throwing an error? Please read how to ask question section (which I don't seem to have the link to) to understand how and what kind of information you should be providing

Comment: my apologize i've edited my original post

Comment: Is `x` an Array that stores the sheet's names in your file? If I'm assuming it right you need to iterate through the elements of `x` in order to make it work, if this is what you need I can help you with the code lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you're looking for something like this?

```
Dim choice As String
Dim x As Variant
Dim v As Variant

x = Array("STD BASE DD", "STD BASE CAB DOOR ONLY", "OPEN BASE CABINET", _
          "1 DRAWER BASE & OPEN", "2 DRAWER BASE", "3 DRAWER BASE", _
          "4 DRAWER BASE", "5 DRAWER BASE")

choice = matsetup.ComboBox1.Text

For Each v In x
    Worksheets(v).Range("H14,H15,H20").Value = choice
Next v
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
Worksheets(x).Range("H14").Value = choice
Worksheets(x).Range("H15").Value = choice
Worksheets(x).Range("H20").Value = choice
```

Comment: no still gives "object doesn't support property or method"